# What's Wrong With This JSON?

Tags: java, json-simple

I'm using json simple to create and parse some json. However, after creating it, I then get a `ParseException` when I do `parser.parse(jStr);`. Below is the value of `jStr`

```
{"score":12,"balls":[[PURPLE_V,134.33325,331.11713,2.0,10.750022,-115,11.0,0],[PURPLE_SPLAT,59.209473,169.87143,0.0,6.2909174,16,11.0,1],[GREEN_V,119.00015,73.71671,-12.0,6.7500067,-35,11.0,0],[ORANGE_V,229.66664,7.4416676,8.0,5.250001,-5,11.0,0]]}
```

What's wrong with this? Can I not do an array of arrays?

Comment: [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) is always useful in debugging invalid json.

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.org/ for these sorts of things, It's really a fabulous tool to have bookmarked.

Comment: You can always try this http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PURPLE_V`, `PURPLE_SPLAT`,`GREEN_V`, `ORANGE_V` should be inside quotes.

Comment: Oh, right! Of course! Thanks. I figured it was something simple I overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

**Try [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/):**

```
{
    "score": 12,
    "balls": [
        [
            PURPLE_V,
            134.33325,
    // ..
```

**output**

```
Parse error on line 4:
...      [            PURPLE_V,          
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', ']'
```

`PURPLE_V`, etc. are not recognized types. *If you wanted them to be Strings, surround 'em with quotes.*

Answer (score 1):

The non-numeric values should be between quotation marks.

```
{"score":12,"balls":[["PURPLE_V",134.33325,331.11713,2.0,10.750022,-115,11.0,0],["PURPLE_SPLAT",59.209473,169.87143,0.0,6.2909174,16,11.0,1],["GREEN_V",119.00015,73.71671,-12.0,6.7500067,-35,11.0,0],["ORANGE_V",229.66664,7.4416676,8.0,5.250001,-5,11.0,0]]}
```

I recommend you to use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON. You might also want to check http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1):

Corrected (with also some formatting for viewing):

```
{"score":12,"balls":[
    ["PURPLE_V",134.33325,331.11713,2.0,10.750022,-115,11.0,0],
    ["PURPLE_SPLAT",59.209473,169.87143,0.0,6.2909174,16,11.0,1],
    ["GREEN_V",119.00015,73.71671,-12.0,6.7500067,-35,11.0,0],
    ["ORANGE_V",229.66664,7.4416676,8.0,5.250001,-5,11.0,0]
]}
```

See http://json.org